# How do i add a clip path for my graph ?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q0ubpmwj/5/

I have been trying to mess around with the clip path so the graph doesnt go outside the axis but i cant seem to get it to work.

Heres a bit of the clip path code i have used but it doesnt seem to work :/

```
var svg = viewer.append("svg").attr('id', 'viewerPins')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var clip = viewer.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("svg:rect")
        .attr("id", "clip-rect")
        .attr("x", "0")
        .attr("y", "0").attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var chartBody = svg.append("g")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        //.call(zoom)
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appending the defs outside of the svg:

```
viewer.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
```

should be

```
svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
```

Comment: i literally just found it out myself haha cheers man shall accept when ready :)